# Disabling "cast from pointer to smaller type uint32_t" error in Clang

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, clang

I'm working on a school project that involves porting a large piece of C++ code on an experimental piece of hardware. Unfortunately, that hardware is 64-bit and the code contains many instances of pointer arithmetic that expects pointers to be 32-bit, i.e. it often does `reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(ptr)`.

Going through them one by one would be very tedious and since this is an experimental project anyway, I'm happy to settle for a "hackish" workaround. So instead I modified the implementation of malloc to ensure it never allocates memory above the 4GB limit. Technically, these casts should therefore be valid.

Question is, how do I explain this to Clang? The error I'm getting is: `error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') loses information`. Is there a way to disable it?

Thanks,
David

Comment: I would try to fix the code instead. Say you hack this successfully. What would you do next year when you need to port it to yet another experimental hardware? You might want to typedef `ptrint` to either `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` based on hardware and then replace all those `reinterpret_cast`s to `ptrint` instead (of course, changing the type on the receiving end too). The first part is easily done with `sed`. The second should be easily doable following compiler warnings, or `grep`.

Comment: You should change your code to handle this. Just because you're altering `malloc` it doesn't mean you're covered. For example, someone might write a custom allocator that's used in a class you don't have access to, and it's allocating at an address above 4GB.

Comment: replace uint32_t by uintptr_t wholesale, then fix remaining cases one by one.

Comment: I am running into the same problem where I am using Clang's static analyzer and clang-tidy to scan code on a 64-bit system that is targeted for a 32-bit system. It keeps throwing this exact error message even though both types are 32 bits wide. I'm not sure how to tell Clang (it's tools, really) that the platform is a 32-bit platform and to stop complaining.

Comment: @PaulBraman: `uintptr_t`

Answer (score 8):

I was able to disable this with `-fms-extensions` after getting this from someone on the [Cpplang Slack](https://cpplang.slack.com/):

> Looking at "DiagnosticSemaKinds.td" it shows up as `err_bad_reinterpret_cast_small_int`, https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/release_50/include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticSemaKinds.td#L6193
>   There are two occurences in "SemaCast.cpp" -- one of which suggests it's sensitive to MS extensions, https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/release_50/lib/Sema/SemaCast.cpp#L2112
>   One could try `-fms-extensions` (hopefully not `-fms-compatibility`), but that would bring all the shebang with it.

Comment: I had this error while trying to cross compile the <memory> header from libstdc++ 5.4.0 with clang 7.0.1 for ARM. The -fms-extensions flag resolved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that you should bite the bullet and fix the code to use the correct integer type. But to answer your question: **No**, you can't disable it, though you can work around it.

Many errors come from warnings. A good thing in general, but if you want to disable the warning, just do it. Since the culprit is probably something like `-Wall` which enables many warnings you should keep on, you should selectively disable this single warning. The error message mentions the diagnostic responsible for error message, e.g. `... [-Wextra-tokens]` (if it doesn't, remove the `-fno-diagnostics-show-option` flag). You can then disable this diagnostic completely by adding `-Wno-extra-tokens` (again, the "extra tokens" warning is an example), or turn it into a non-fatal warning by means of `-Wno-error=extra-tokens`.

However, this specific error is not due to a warning and I can't find any option to disable errors (makes sense, since most errors are fatal).

But to just truncate the integer value and not having to fix all the wrong uses of `uint32_t` *just yet*, you could use `static_cast<uint32_t>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr))`. Needless to say, this will still be wrong.

Comment: I wish your idea worked. It does not because `Wno-error` is meant for **warnings** not fatal errors (look at the manual). Not only that but `fdiagnostic-show-option` will also only work on warnings and not fatal errors. Points for the attempt at a workaround though.

Comment: @ck_ I didn't realize the error in the question is actually an error by default, not a warning-turned-error. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

how about using uintptr_t, most of your pointer arithmetic may still works.

Comment: OP said he doesn't want it. I can easily imagine a situation where rewriting code using `uintptr_t` is not feasible (e.g. serializing pointers to 4 bytes and using hard-coded offsets).

Answer (score 0):

Save this piece of code as `mycast.hpp` and add `-include mycast.hpp` to your `Makefile`.

```
#include <cstdint>

template<typename U, typename T>
U Reinterpret_cast(T *x) {
    return (U)(uintptr_t)x;
}

template<typename U, typename T>
U Reinterpret_cast(T &x) {
    return *(U*)&x;
}

#define reinterpret_cast Reinterpret_cast
```

They should do their job unless your code is too tricky.

Your strategy will not work for stack-allocated objects, be careful!!  You can insert some debugging/logging logic to `Reinterpret_cast` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same problem in a project without C++11, and worked around it like this:

```
inline int PtrToInt(void* ptr)
{
    void* clang[1];
    clang[0] = ptr;
    return *(int*)clang;
}
```